Django rest framework custom api response for the whole project not working
I need to make my API responses consistent based on my custom api_respone:
def api_response(success, message, data=None, error=None, 
  status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK, email_verified=None, token=None):
  response = {
    'success': success,
    'message': message,
  }
  if data:
    response['data'] = data
  if error:
    response['error'] = error
  if email_verified is not None:
    response['email_verified'] = email_verified
  if token is not None:
    response['token'] = token
  return Response(response, status=status_code)

I created an exception handler:
   def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
response = exception_handler(exc, context)

if response is not None:
    custom_response_data = {
        'success': False,
        'message': response.data.get('detail', 'An error occurred.'),
        'status_code': response.status_code,
    }
    response.data = custom_response_data

else:
    custom_response_data = {
        'success': False,
        'message': str(exc),
        'status_code': status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
    }
    return api_response(
        success=custom_response_data['success'],
        message=custom_response_data['message'],
        status_code=custom_response_data['status_code']
    )

return response

and added it in the setting.py:
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'backend.exceptions.custom_exception_handler',

But it didn't work at all and as a a result, I now have some custom responses (Hard coded) and others (The exception or permission exceptions) are not, which is not good.
How do I properly solve my problem?
here is an example of a view code:
class PasswordUpdateView(APIView):
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]

def post(self, request):
    user = request.user
    serializer = UserPasswordUpdateSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.update(user, serializer.validated_data)
        return api_response(True, "Password updated successfully")
    return api_response(False, "Password update failed", error=serializer.errors, status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

In this case, if the jwt token is expired, the exception response returned is not formatted based on my custom api_response.
I hope I made my situation clear. Thanks in advance

Did you put 'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'backend.exceptions.custom_exception_handler', at the top of the settings dict?
The order is important

Yes, but it didn't work,
I am using the default response from Django until I can find a suitable solution
